# Check given string in file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check a string in a file irrespective of its case.

Sting is:

```
env=electron
```

This have to show matching if file shell.txt contain the give string in any form irrespective of case

Example
**shell.txt**

```
Electron 
electron
ELECTRON
ElEcTRon   /* upper lower combination in any order have to chow matching */
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please stop putting kernel tags on questions that are completely unrelated to kernel work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -i "electron" shell.txt
```

The -i is for ignore-case..

Comment: +1 and if you only want a quicker yes/no answer, add the `-q` flag